# How to spawn each child process in separate pid namespace

Tags: linux, kernel, process, namespace, sandbox

How to spawn each child in a separate PID namespace using `unshare` (without `CLONE_NEWPID flag in child process clone syscall`). I am able to successfully spawn first child in PID namespace but I am not sure how to spawn the second child in another PID namespace.

Psuedo code of the parent process

```
1 unshare CLONE_NEWPID
2 spawn child1
3
4 unshare CLONE_NEWPID
5 spawn child2
```

Here child1 entered into the separate PID namespace and got the PID as 1. When the execution reached line 4 it threw `Sys(EINVAL)` error.

Comment: Can you show real code (the smallest example, that shows the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the manual `unshare CLONE_NEWPID` acts on the calling process, not the child. Calling this multiple times seems redundant. After the 1st call all children are in a new pid namespace.

To put them in there own, you need a different parent to call `unshare CLONE_NEWPID`.

Try

```
repeat:
    fork
    if child:
        unshare CLONE_NEWPID
        spawn
```

This is all untested, and just what I would try next.
I am also reading that you need to use `clone`.

Comment: `From reading the manual unshare CLONE_NEWPID acts on the calling process, not the child.` 

Nice, Seems I missed noticing this, any reference you can provide?

Comment: Can you update, when you get it to work.

Comment: It worked for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be nice to have an account of what worked.